# Problems with creating a pipelineJob environment variables via groovy script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

does this https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-environmentVariables-groovy actually work?

Probably more of an plugin issue.

groovy scripts to set env vars seem to work for freestyle job. But I can't get them to work with pipeline jobs.
They don't cause any errors but the environment variable won't get set either.

Anyone else played around with it?

```
pipelineJob('example') {
  environmentVariables {
    env('ONE', '1')
    env('TWO', '2')
    groovy('''
    def a = 1
    return [THREE: 3 * a]
    ''')
  }
  
  definition {
    cps {
      script('''
      pipeline {
        agent any
        
        stages {
          stage('Env') {
            steps {
              sh 'env'
            }
          }
        }
      }
      
      ''')
    }
  }
}
```

thx

Comment: In my experience this plugin generally works pretty well. Are you using it for creating new jobs? And are the env vars not set in the created job?

Comment: The env vars are not set. I used the example from documentation. And then added a small pipeline with a shell script: sh ' env'

Comment: Could you please add your dsl code and the generated job to the question?

Comment: @smelm added example